# How to list stored samba shares credentials in Windows10

Tags: windows, windows-10, network-shares, samba

I have a samba share on my NAS and mounted it in Windows-10 for a couple of days.

Then I removed the share on Windows, however it is still trying to access it - but with incorrect credentials. I know it because I get warnings from my NAS that my Windows exceeded the limit of failed login attempts.

It happens each time when I open `File Explorrer` on Windows. If it had used the original credentials from NAS - it would get the access. I suppose - windows is trying to use my primary Active Directory credentials - which are different from my NAS's.

And I wonder - where is the information stored? What tells File Explorer what credentials should it use for a given network share? Is there some registry entry, or what?

Comment: Do you see the NAS in Explorer somewhere (especially under Network)?

Comment: No, I don't see it as a share anywhere, but I see some in `Quick access`. The list of recent files is full of items from NAS, that are not accessible anymore.

Comment: You can remove entries in Quick Access, or other references anywhere else, to stop having these warnings. Also remove all references in the Credential Manager.

Answer (score -1):

Windows stores all that inside "Windows Credential Manager"

[image]

Alternatively, for Samba shares you can use:

`net use /delete \\NAS\ShareName` inside powershell admin

Comment: Yes and not. It stores some credentials there, but not those that are being used by Samba.

Comment: Have you tried `net use /delete \\NAS\ShareName` inside powershell admin?